# why doesn't this compile when using std::max and c++/CLI?

Tags: types, c++-cli, max

Can anyone please explain why the following will compile

```
int a = aAssignments[i]->Count;
int b = fInstanceData->NumRequiredEmpsPerJob[i];
fInstanceData->NumSlotsPerJob[i] = max(a,b);
```

but

```
fInstanceData->NumSlotsPerJob[i] = max((int)(aAssignments[i]->Count), (int)(fInstanceData->NumRequiredEmpsPerJob[i])); //why on earth does this not work?
```

wont? The error it gives is `error C2665: 'std::max' : none of the 7 overloads could convert all the argument types`

The variable `aAssigmments` is of type `array<List<int>^>^` and `fInstanceData->NumRequiredEmpsPerJob` is of type `array<int>^`

The manual for `std::max` states that it takes values by reference, so it's clearly doing this implicitly in the first example, so why can't the compiler do the same for integer values returned by the count property, as in the second example? Can I get a reference to an int explicitly?

Comment: How does it even compile that `Count` property, arrays have a `Length` property.

Comment: @leppie It's an array of lists, I'm indexing the array at `i` and counting the elements of that list.

Comment: no worries - thanks for taking the time to look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(int)(aAssignments[i]->Count)` will call the property getter.  But it evaluates to a temporary variable (rvalue) which cannot bind to a non-const reference.

According to my documentation on `std::max`, the parameters should be const references and everything should work.

What happens if you explicitly specify the template type parameter, e.g.

`max<int>((int)(aAssignments[i]->Count), (int)(fInstanceData->NumRequiredEmpsPerJob[i]))`

?

What about `max<int>(a + 0, b + 0)` ?

Comment: If I explicitly specify the template type it accepts the first argument `aAssignments[i]->Count` but not the second argument, giving me a `cannot convert parameter 2 from 'int' to 'const int &'` error. Adding zero to this argument works though! *But there must be a better way...*

Comment: What's going on is this: The second argument already describes an lvalue of type `int`, so the compiler removes the cast (I believe erroneously).  Since the lvalue is on the managed heap, it is subject to being moved by the GC and needs a managed reference (`int%`) instead of C++ reference (`int&`).  The value needs to be copied into a temporary, which is not on the managed heap, so it binds just fine, and the cast SHOULD have done that.  Looks like a compiler bug.

Comment: It's a compiler bug, and affects native C++ as well.  Will post a bug report link momentarily.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/615622/identity-cast-to-non-reference-type-violates-standard

Answer (score 1):

List<>.Count is not a field, it is a property.  You can't create a unmanaged reference to a managed property, obtaining the property value requires calling the property accessor.  Short from your first approach, the better mousetrap here is to use Math::Max().