# Should a C++ temporary be constant?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, language-lawyer

I have a C++ class that has the following interface:

```
class F {
public:
    F(int n, int d);
    // no other constructors/assignment constructors defined
    F& operator *= (const F&);
    F& operator *= (int);
    int n() const;
    int d() const;
};
```

And I have the following code:

```
const F a{3, 7};
const F b{5, 10};
auto result = F{a} *= b; // How does this compile?
```

Under Visual Studio (VS) 2013, the commented line compiles without error. Under VS2015 , error C2678 is produced:

```
error C2678: binary '*=': no operator found 
    which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const F' 
    (or there is no acceptable conversion)
note: could be 'F &F::operator *=(const F &)'
note: or       'F &F::operator *=(int)'
note: while trying to match the argument list '(const F, const F)'
```

My expectation was that `F{a}` would create a non-const temporary copy of `a` to which `operator *= (b)` would be applied, after which the temporary object would be assigned to `result`. I did not expect the temporary to be a constant. Interestingly: `auto result = F(a) *= b;` compiles without error in VS2015, which I thought should be semantically the same.

My question is: which behaviour is correct VS2015 or VS2013 & why?

Many thanks

Comment: Looks like a bug at first sight, `F{a}` should be non-const

Comment: can you post a MCVE just to make sure there aren't any other factors?

Comment: Clearly it lost its marbles when it tried to infer a (const F, const F) initializer list.  Just use `F(a)` instead.  Use connect.microsoft.com to report bugs.

Comment: @HansPassant yeah, this is puzzling bug, it seems like it may be related to [this other puzzling one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34160614/1708801).

Comment: First time this bug was noted on Stack Overflow (I believe): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986522

Comment: Note Visual Studio has several similar issue as noted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26508755/1708801) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16380966/1708801) and the solutions to those problems do not fix this one so they are not related to any of the old issues I know of.

Comment: @M.M right it should not be constant unless the specifier itself is const, although there are more issues than that.

Comment: Thank you all and especially to @shafikyaghmour. I am inclined to the view that this is indeed a VS bug. Ben Voigt reported something very similar 5 years ago against VS2010. MS closed it with a promise that it would be fixed in the next version. That was fulfilled until VS2015, so this ought to be a failed regression. More news shortly...

Comment: @MarvinLittlewood does that mean you are filing a bug report? If so it may be worth mentioning [this issue as well](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34160614/1708801) they may be related although it is not clear to me if they are.

Comment: @ShafnikYaghmour thanks for the suggestion: I have added the issue to my report: [VisualStudio/feedback/details/2178733](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2178733/temporary-copy-of-const-type-incorrectly-results-in-an-lvalue)

Answer (score 8):

Visual Studio 2015 is not producing the correct result for:

```
F{a}
```

The result should be a prvalue(*gcc and clang both have this result*) but it is producing an lvalue. I am using the following modified version of the OP's code to produce this result:

```
#include <iostream>

class F {
public:
    F(int n, int d) :n_(n), d_(d) {};
    F(const F&) = default ;
    F& operator *= (const F&){return *this; }
    F& operator *= (int) { return *this; }
    int n() const { return n_ ; }
    int d() const { return d_ ; }
    int n_, d_ ;
};

template<typename T>
struct value_category {
    static constexpr auto value = "prvalue";
};

template<typename T>
struct value_category<T&> {
    static constexpr auto value = "lvalue";
};

template<typename T>
struct value_category<T&&> {
    static constexpr auto value = "xvalue";
};

#define VALUE_CATEGORY(expr) value_category<decltype((expr))>::value

int main()
{
  const F a{3, 7};
  const F b{5, 10};   
  std::cout << "\n" <<  VALUE_CATEGORY( F{a} ) <<  "\n";
}
```

Hat tip to [Luc Danton for the VALUE_CATEGORY() code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16638081/1708801).

Visual Studio using [webcompiler](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) which has a relatively recent version produces:

```
lvalue
```

which must be *const* in this case to produce the error we are seeing. While both gcc and clang (*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/FAim3ir6V3qHQWn9)*) produce:

```
prvalue
```

This may be related to equally puzzling Visual Studio bug [std::move of string literal - which compiler is correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34160614/1708801).

Note we can get the same issue with gcc and clang using a *const F*:

```
using cF = const F ;
auto result = cF{a} *= b;
```

so not only is Visual Studio giving us the wrong value category but it also arbitrarily adding a cv-qualifier.

As Hans noted in his comments to your question using `F(a)` produces the expected results since it correctly produces a prvalue.

The relevant section of the draft C++ standard is section `5.2.3` *[expr.type.conv]* which says:

> Similarly, a simple-type-specifier or typename-specifier followed by a braced-init-list creates a temporary
>   object of the specified type direct-list-initialized (8.5.4) with the specified braced-init-list, and **its value is
>   that temporary object as a prvalue.**

Note, as far as I can tell this is not the ["old MSVC lvalue cast bug"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26508755/1708801). The solution to that issue is to use `/Zc:rvalueCast` which does not fix this issue. This issue also differs in the incorrect addition of a cv-qualifier which as far as I know does not happen with the previous issue.

Comment: oh, it's the old MSVC lvalue cast bug. Figured they might have not perpetuated that to list initialization...

Comment: @M.M how do you know? As far as I can tell the solution [as mentioned here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26508755/1708801) is to use `/Zc:rvalueCast ` which does not fix this issue.

Comment: @M.M it is definitely similar but the fact that the provided solution does not fix this issue and the result is a const lvalue which seems not to be the case other situations. So this seems related but distinct.

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts it's a bug in VS2015, because if you specify user defined copy constructor:

```
F(const F&);
```

or make variable `a` non-const code will be compiled successfully.

Looks like object's constness from `a` transferred into newly created object.

Comment: What if you make the copy ctor explicit?  It seems to me it's using it as a cast because there is no need for a bona fide copy.

Answer (score 0):

Visual C++ has had a bug for some time where an identity cast doesn't produce a temporary, but refers to the original variable.

Bug report here: [identity cast to non-reference type violates standard](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/615622/identity-cast-to-non-reference-type-violates-standard)

Comment: I don't believe it is the same bug, as far as I understand that is that is the same issue as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26508755/1708801) and the solution is to use `/Zc:rvalueCast` which does not fix the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision:

> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are permitted to omit the 
>   copy- and move-constructors of class objects even if copy/move constructor 
>   and the destructor have observable side-effects.
>
> .......
>
> When a **nameless temporary**, not bound to any references, would be moved or 
>   copied into an object of the same type (**ignoring top-level cv-**
>   **qualification**), the copy/move is omitted. When that temporary is 
>   constructed, it is constructed directly in the storage where it would 
>   otherwise be moved or copied to. When the nameless temporary is the 
>   argument of a return statement, this variant of copy elision is known as 
>   RVO, "return value optimization".

So the compiler has the option to ignore the copy (which in this case would act as an implicit cast to non-const type).